# Truncation of vector values based on another vector

Tags: r

Here is the general algorithm I wish to implement in R:

```
if (x[i]>y[i]) x[i] = y[i]
```

`x` and `y` are of course vectors. This problem looks like a loop is the solution.

Comment: If this were Java I would want an "if then" statement.  But, this is not Java and I am new to R.

Comment: If its an indexing problem, you should note that indexing is 1-based in R, rather than 0-based as it is in Java. However, as noted in the answer below, you should try to avoid loops in R and use vectorised functions if possible.

Comment: It would be helpful if you didn't use the same exact subject (verbatim!) for different questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of possibilities. First with the ifelse function (since the if (){ } else{ } constuct does not work on vectors):

```
x <- ifelse( x > y, y, x)
```

Or with logical indexing:

```
x[ x>y ] <- y[ x>y ]
```

Both of these assume that x and y are the same length and are implicitly comparing and assigning elementwise so no need for an index

Comment: > x=c(1,2,3)
> y=c(1,1,1)
> x<- ifelse(x>y,y,x)
> x
[1] 1 1 1

Comment: I need it to change x=c(1,2,3) to x=c(1,2,1), so I need to change a part of the vector not just swap out the vectors.

Comment: Jermoe - the you need to explain how you want to do the changing. In my math 2 > 1. If `y <- c(1,1,1)` and `x <- 1:3` (as per your comment) then given the "general algorithm" in your Q I need to change the last two elements of `x` to be their equivalent element in `y` because `x > y` yields `[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE`, hence, your algorithm states that `x` should end up as `c(1,1,1)`. Can you explain why the second element of `x` (2), which is bigger than element 2 in `y` (1), should not get replaced with the corresponding value from `y`, which is 1?

Comment: Perhaps I could be clearer? I showed above that `x > y` gave `[1] FALSE TRUE TRUE`. So given your stated algorithm, we **must** change both the 2nd and 3rd elements of `x` to be their corresponding values in `y`. As `y` is a vector of 1s, the 2nd and 3rd elements of `x` are replaced by 1s. The first element of `x` is unchanged, but as it was already a 1, it looks like `y` was swapped in for `x`. So either your Q contains a mistake and the general algorithm is not the general algorithm stated, or you haven't grepped what Dwin's answer is doing.

Comment: I found the mistake in my test.  Forgive me.  I am learning that R handles data very differently than I am used to.

Answer (score 2):

Good, DWin showed you already why you absolutely don't need a loop in R. But apparently you don't want to do what you asked, or your comment wouldn't make sense whatsoever.

If you want to choose which ones you want to change, you just add an extra logical vector to the solution of DWin, eg:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 10:1

# say I want to change every second index
id <- seq.int(length(x))%%2

ifelse(x>y & id,y,x)
```

You can do what you want, as long as id :

- is as long as x and y
- contains 1/TRUE for can change and 0/FALSE for cannot change

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer is surely

```
x <- pmax(x,y)
```